# Python Pandas OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to execute the below code:-

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_columns = None

data = {
  "type": [1, 2, 3],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45],
  "cal_str": [None,None,None],
  "status": [1,0,1]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df.loc[df.status == 1, 'cal_str'] = open(df.type.to_string()+'.txt', "r").readlines()[0]

print((df))
```

It is giving me error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '0    1\n1    2\n2    3.txt'

Actually, I want to add the text from txt file to `cal_str` based on the type.

So, after execution my data should look like:

```
data = {
  "type": [1, 2, 3],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45],
  "cal_str": ["text under 1.txt file",None,"text under 3.txt file"],
  "status": [1,0,1]
}
```

I have text files named as per the values in `type`. So, here I am having 3 files, `1.txt` , `2.txt` & `3.txt`. Now I want to add the text file data as per *type* in ***cal_str***.

Comment: That makes sense. pandas to_string() is a string representation of the DataFrame so that's why you have the \n (new line characters). You might be better off with something like this: `'{some sort of separator here}'.join(df.type.values)`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you intend to perform with this code? What is the input? What is the expected output? Please update your post to add relevant information. Also see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @tripleee & jlandercy I have updated the question with more details. Hope that works.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
str(df['type'].tolist())
```

produces:

```py
'[1, 2, 3]'
```